# Post and query mysql database

Tags: php, jquery

on one page I have the following code:

```
$("#photolist").dragsort({
    dragBetween: true,
    dragEnd: saveOrder,
    placeHolderTemplate: "<li class='placeHolder'><div></div></li>"
});

function saveOrder() {
    var data = $("#photolist li").map(function() {
        return $(this).children().find('img').attr('id');
    }).get();

    $("input[name=SortOrder]").val(data.join("|"));
    var map =  $('input[name=SortOrder]').val();
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: 'updatephotoposition.php',
        data: "map=" + map,
        success: function(){  
            alert("success");
        }
    });
};
```

It is definitely firing because the alert is functioning.

on my page updatephotoposition.php I use the following code:

```
<?php
include '../dbconnect.php';
$map = explode('|', $_POST['map']);
foreach ($map as $position => $ID)
{
    $query = "UPDATE Photos SET Position = '$position' WHERE PhotoID = '$ID';";
    $result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());
}
?>
```

But my database isn't getting updated, can anyone see a problem with this set up?

Post data sent: `82|83|84|85|86|81|87|88|89`

EDIT: This has suddenly started working

Comment: and the post data is...?

Comment: This is a non-constructive "debugging"-type question, not a question regarding any particular aspect of any particular language.

Comment: Trying `echo` ing `$query`. Your JavaScript should then alert the query, and you can check it out. Maybe there's a typo somewhere. If nothing else, you can take that string and run it through the database yourself, and see if it points out any errors.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc I'm not sure how to get the `$query` back to my first page. to alert it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be related to your mysql. Your field 'Position' could be conflicting with the reserved function name POSITION (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_position).

Try popping some accented quotes around your field name to escape it:

```
`Position`
```

Comment: Possibly, though I'd expect an SQL error out of that. Likely the loop also isn't being entered.

Comment: Could you post what an accented quote is? I'm not sure what symbol that is. thanks.

Comment: Tried with the quotes, still nothing :(

Comment: Tomalak added the code for me, sorry, bit of a newbie.

Comment: suddenly started working, could be due to the quotes :)